# Help to fix error"No mesh data to join" Wallet 3D

Tags: rigging, objects

I´m doing a wallet 3D in Blender.

My goal is the rotation of the wallet ribbon with the snap button and the square with textil material linked/connect to the wallet ribbon.

So i add an armature with bones to accompany the wallet ribbon, then i press CTRL+J to join the square with textil material with the snap button with the wallet ribbon it appears me this kind of error "No mesh data to join".

Another issue when I rotate the second bone at the top of the wallet, both the push button and the square with the textile material are separated from the ribbon of the wallet when the rotation is made.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me to resolve this issue.

I would like you to send me the steps in a detailed and simple way to make it easier for me to understand.

Below I send my .blend file to help me

I hope your reply as soon as possible

[image]

[image]
But when

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HK9VaYSsvIICsqKbIsTUPiGA1z5t_ghn/view?usp=sharing